# How (is it possible) to use ta.barssince to compare past values with current value?

Tags: comparison, pine-script, pine-script-v5, indicator

How (is it even possible) to make a condition for ta.barssince which refernces current value, this bar, and not past values?

For example, I'd like to find out when was the last time that price has closed below the current candle close. How (is that possible) to do it?

Obvious attempts like ta.barssince(close<close[0]) do not work because it compares past's close to past's close[0] (which is identical) and not current close[0]

Comment: I personaly use `array` and not `ta.barssince()` to do exactly that. If this will answer your question, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this is found to be impossible, and the only option is to use loops

Answer (score 0):

close is the same as close[0]
If you want to access the previous close value, it's close[1]

Comment: Yes but that's not what I want. close[1] does not work in barssince, since it compares every bar's condition to that bar's close[1], meaning, to that bar's previous. I want to compare past bars to an exact bar value

Comment: Are you looking to get the number of candles since that event happened OR the timestamp when it happened?

Comment: daveatt I am looking to get the number of candles that closed below current candle.

Comment: Got it, and you want the number of candles that closed below current candle with the counter starting at the current candle right?
Meaning the next candle closing below will set the counter to 1
You should save the current candle close in a global variable for that

Answer (score 0):

```
float my_close = 0.    
if close < close[1]
   my_close := close

since_below_close = ta.barssince(close < my_close)
plot(since_below_close)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, plots NAs

Comment: That's the point of my question. IT seems this can't be done without for/while loops. Because condition is checked back in time, so, if you write barssince (close < my_close), it will compare past close to PAST my_close, not present my_close

Comment: ok got it, did you try with a for/while loop already?